# Swift 2.0 - variable copied in closure?

Tags: swift2, closures, capture, self

I have an array of dictionaries class instance, outlined below:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var array = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    // tableview delegates

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        print(“array address: \(unsafeAddressOf(array))”) // 0x000000015cf0ebd0

        let option = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: “Option”, handler: { [weak self] (_, _) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

            print(“array address1: \(unsafeAddressOf(strongSelf.array))” // 0x000000015cd10c50
        })

        return [option]
    }    
}
```

why is the address of `array` is changed (`0x000000015cf0ebd0` vs `0x000000015cd10c50`) as I just capture it in `UITableViewRowAction` initialization?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nature of `unsafeAddressOf` and Swift Arrays.

A simplified example you can test in the Playground.
(No closure, no strongSelf...)

```
import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"
class MyClass {
    var array = [[String: AnyObject]]()

}

let obj1 = MyClass()

let ptr1 = unsafeAddressOf(obj1.array)
let ptr2 = unsafeAddressOf(obj1.array)

print(ptr1 == ptr2)
```

Tested in Xcode 7.3.1 (Swift 2.2.1) a few times and all printed "false".

The signature of `unsafeAddressOf` is:

```
func unsafeAddressOf(object: AnyObject) -> UnsafePointer<Void>
```

As you know Swift Arrays are value types and you cannot pass them to `AnyObject`. So, when "bridging to Objective-C" feature is available, your `array` is converted to `NSArray`. This conversion is done in a "hard-to-predict" manner, which means, at any time this conversion is made, Swift may allocate a new `NSArray` instance.

In general, you should not expect something "firm" from `unsafeAddressOf` when applied to Swift Arrays or other value types.

Comment: Thank to your question, now I know `Array` is value-typed, I thought it should be reference-typed. My problem is: I update `array` but always fail to get it updated. Now I know I was working with its copy, not the actual `array`. Is there a way to "force" the compiler to use it as a reference?

Comment: The simplest and most steady way is declaring your `array` as `NSArray`. It loses some type information, but can contain elements of `[String: AnyObject]`, can be casted to `[[String: AnyObject]]` with `as!` when needed. Someone can show you more Swift-y proposals, but they may be a little more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are assigning self to variable `strongSelf`, causing the value of `self` to be copied to the new variable.

Remember that when you assign a variable to another, it's the value that's copied from one to another, not the reference to the memory allocation.

You can try this by printing exactly the same way you are doing the first time:

```
print("array address: \(unsafeAddressOf(self.array))")
```

You need to add `self` in order to access the `array` class member when inside a closure block.